# Swift-NSTimer & setNeedDisplay

Tags: ios, swift, setneedsdisplay

```
    NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(setNeedsDisplay) userInfo:self repeats:YES];
```

I want know how to write the code above in swift.thank u.

Answer (score 0):

Sample usage `NSTimer's` timer schedule event -

```
// create a timer instance 
let timer = NSTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: "timerEventTriggered:", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

// adding timer to current run loop
NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop().addTimer(timer, forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes)

// implement the event which is triggered by scheduled timer
func timerEventTriggered(timer:NSTimer!) {
    ...
}
```

**Note** : This was just the sample usage, you can change the variable and method names as per your context.

Answer (score 0):

```
var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: Selector("yourFunction"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)


func yourFunction() {
    // Do something
 }


/////other way.......
 dispatch_after(timer, dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in

     //do same like in yourFunction()

   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The code can be written as

**Swift 2**

```
var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("setNeedsDisplay"), userInfo: self, repeats: true)

func setNeedsDisplay() {

}
```

**Swift 3, 4, 5**

```
var timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(self.setNeedsDisplay), userInfo: self, repeats: true)

@objc func setNeedsDisplay() {

}
```

Comment: override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        sublayer = CALayer()
        sublayer!.position = self.view.center
        sublayer!.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)
        view.layer.addSublayer(sublayer)
        sublayer!.delegate = self.sublayer
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("setNeedsDisplay"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
    override func displayLayer(layer: CALayer!) {
        var str: NSString = NSString(string: "bg\(randomState).jpg")
        sublayer!.contents = UIImage(named: str)?.CGImage
    }

Comment: There are something wrong. ViewController setNeedsDisplay]: unrecognized selector sent to instance. Can you help me find why?

Comment: I see. setNeedsDisplay is a method of UIView class. In your case you are calling it on self i.e. UIVIewController. In you call replace **target: self** to **target:self.view**

Answer (score 0):

```
var timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(self.setNeedsDisplay), userInfo: self, repeats: true)
```

Comment: Could you add some more explanation and a reference, perhaps?